# Replace a string of characters with some special characters?

Tags: python

when i input some texts/strings, i want them to appear either as hidden or with some special characters(as we do while entering password). . . how can i implement it in a python program?
pls help me.

Answer (score 4):

Use [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html)

```
import getpass
getpass.getpass()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module.